# GMM efficiency vs IV efficiency condition

Tags: regression, instrumental-variables, generalized-moments

Let the true model be

$$
Y = X_1\beta_1 + X_2\beta_2 + u
$$

but $X_2$ is omitted, so we estimate

$$
Y = X_1\gamma_1 + e
$$

by a valid instrument $Z$, so $\gamma_1$ is the 2SLS estimator.

Assume now, $E[\pmb{z}_ie_i]=0$ and $E[e_i^2\pmb{z}_i\pmb{z}_i']=V \succcurlyeq 0$.

What is an additional condition under which GMM **cannot** be more efficient than IV? And is it necessary or sufficient?

I only know that GMM is efficient if we use a weighting matrix proportional to $V^{-1}$ and that Cramer-Rao bound is attained asymptotically, but I think this is only amongst other GMM like estimators and doesn't really say anything about IV comparison.